# Error on publishing apps to Google Chrome Store from the Developer dashboard

Tags: google-drive-api

I've already published 3 test apps for Google Chrome Store without problems, but in my last one, when I am trying to publish the app I got an error"

> "* This item is not allowed to link to the API console project specified in the manifest. You may only link to an API Console project if one of thers of your Chrome Webstore project is a writer or owner of the API Console project."

I have checked the API console project and application has the same owner, me.

The manifest I have used is :

```
{
    "name": "Development",
    "description": "Developer test location",
    "container" : "GOOGLE_DRIVE",
    "api_console_project_id" : "[xxxxxx]",
    "version": "1.51",
    "icons": 
    {
        "96": "96x96.png",
        "128": "128x128.png"
    },
    "app": 
    {
        "launch": 
        {
            "web_url": "[xxxxx]"
        }
    }
}
```

where the [xxxxxx] are real data and I am developing an app for the Google Drive.

The wider part is this, I tried to update one of my old apps (that are already published to testers) and I get the same error, so did anything change from Google part or I am missing something?

Comment: I tried a new publish this morning and it worked, so I guess it was a google problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this on my test Chrome Web Store listing. There is definitely something wrong, I guess this error makes sense if you don't own the Google APIs Console project but not in these cases where we use the same account for both the Chrome Web Store listing and the APIs Console project.

We are letting the Google Drive engineering team know about this issue. We hope to have this fixed soon and I will keep you informed here.

We apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: This now seems to be fixed. Can anyone try and repport?